# Make previous applications Iphone 5 compatible

Tags: xcode

Iimages on the application are appearing good. There is a blank screen at the bottom because the images do not fit the size of the IPhone screen. Is there any simple and quick solution to this or do I have to make separate screens for iPhone 5?

Comment: AFAIK there is no solution for this. You can have any image (like header image of app) at the bottom for iPhone5

Comment: or we can make separate views for iphoen5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is solved the best is way is to make separate views if your application is a small application and uses fewer views in it.